# How can I check with a loop if a group of strings is empty or not?

Tags: python, string, loops

I am trying to go through a loop of strings (alias names) in order to apply the unidecode, and to avoid the error of not having aliases words in some cases, I am using an if/else to check if there is a string or not, so I can apply the unidecode.
I tried by checking the length of the word by doing this code, but it keeps saying "list' object has no attribute 'element". I am not sure what should I do.

```
alias=record.findall("./person/names/aliases/alias")    
alias_name=[element.text for element in alias]         
if  len(alias_name.element.text)!=0:
        alias_names_str = ','.join(alias_name)
        alias_names_str=unidecode.unidecode(alias_names_str)
else: 
        alias_name.element.text="NONE"
```

Comment: Code you provided is incomplete. What is `record`?

Comment: sorry, it's a path for a xml document:

 
import unidecode
records= tree.xpath("/records/record")

for record in records:
    alias=record.findall("./person/names/aliases/alias")  
    alias_name=[element.text for element in alias]          
    if  len(alias_name.element.text)!=0:
            alias_names_str = ','.join(alias_name)
            alias_names_str=unidecode.unidecode(alias_names_str)
    else: 
            alias_name.element.text="NONE"

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like an XML or HTML decoder.

```
# alias is an iterable of elements
alias=record.findall("./person/names/aliases/alias")

# alias_names is a list of strings, you have already dereferenced the text
alias_names=[element.text for element in alias]         

if  len(alias_names)>0:
        alias_names_str = ','.join(alias_names)
        alias_names_str = unidecode.unidecode(alias_names_str)
else: 
        alias_names_str = "NONE"
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you! yes, I want to apply the unidecode to remove the diacritics of those strings. Your code helped, then I needed to change some details and it worked!

Thank you so much! :)